# Improve performance on converting a flattened LINQ2SQL result to a 3 level hierarchic object

Tags: performance, linq-to-sql, lambda, hierarchy

I have a large data set being retrieved by a stored procedure call from our MSSQL 2008 DB. The dataset is a 300,000+ rows of flattened hierarchical data (Events>InventorySpaces>ScheduledInventorySpaces) or (Parent>Child>GrandChild)

For processing reasons I need to convert this into a hierarchical object model and perform analysis against it.

I am experiencing processing delays in creating the hierarchical object and would like to get the community's opinion on how to speed this up. PLINQ? Lambda Joins? Etc?

The class definitions are as follows:

```
    public class Evt
{
    public int NetCodeID { get; set; }
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public int SiteID { get; set; }
    public bool HomeGame { get; set; }
    public string Days { get; set; }
    public int DayBit { get; set; }
    public int EventIDRC { get; set; }
    public List<InvSpace> InvSpaces { get; set; }

    public Evt()
    {
    }

    public Evt(int netcodeid, int eventid, int siteid, bool homegame, string days, int daybit, int eventidrc)
    {
        this.NetCodeID = netcodeid;
        this.EventID = eventid;
        this.SiteID = siteid;
        this.HomeGame = homegame;
        this.Days = days;
        this.DayBit = daybit;
        this.EventIDRC = eventidrc;
        this.InvSpaces = new List<InvSpace>();
    }

    public Evt(int netcodeid, int eventid, int siteid, bool homegame, string days, int daybit, int eventidrc, List<InvSpace> invspaces)
    {
        this.NetCodeID = netcodeid;
        this.EventID = eventid;
        this.SiteID = siteid;
        this.HomeGame = homegame;
        this.Days = days;
        this.DayBit = daybit;
        this.EventIDRC = eventidrc;
        this.InvSpaces = invspaces;
    }

}

class EvtResultEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<USP_GetAvailableScheduledInventorySpacesResult>
{
    public bool Equals(USP_GetAvailableScheduledInventorySpacesResult x, USP_GetAvailableScheduledInventorySpacesResult y)
    {
        return Equals(x.EventID, y.EventID);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(USP_GetAvailableScheduledInventorySpacesResult x)
    {
        return x.EventID.GetHashCode();
    }
}

    public class InvSpace
{
    public int InventorySpaceID { get; set; }
    public string InventoryName { get; set; }
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public int InventoryClearanceTypeBit { get; set; }
    public int InventoryClearanceTypeID { get; set; }
    public int InventoryProductTypeID { get; set; }
    public int InventoryTypeID { get; set; }
    public int AvailableLength { get; set; }
    public List<string> InventoryGroupAdvertiserCategories { get; set; }
    public List<string> AdvertiserCategories { get; set; }
    public int? Positions { get; set; }
    public List<ScheduledInvSpace> ScheduledInvSpaces { get; set; }

    public InvSpace()
    {
    }

    public InvSpace(int inventoryspaceid, string inventoryname, int ordernumber, int inventoryclearancetypebit, int inventoryclearancetypeid, int inventoryproducttypeid, int inventorytypeid)
    {
        this.InventorySpaceID = inventoryspaceid;
        this.InventoryName = inventoryname;
        this.OrderNumber = ordernumber;
        this.InventoryClearanceTypeBit = inventoryclearancetypebit;
        this.InventoryClearanceTypeID = inventoryclearancetypeid;
        this.InventoryProductTypeID = inventoryproducttypeid;
        this.InventoryTypeID = inventorytypeid;
        this.InventoryGroupAdvertiserCategories = new List<string>();
        this.AdvertiserCategories = new List<string>();
        this.ScheduledInvSpaces = new List<ScheduledInvSpace>();
        this.AvailableLength = ScheduledInvSpaces.Count*5;
    }

    public InvSpace(int inventoryspaceid, string inventoryname, int ordernumber, int inventoryclearancetypebit, int inventoryclearancetypeid, int inventoryproducttypeid, int inventorytypeid, string inventorygroupadvertisercategories, string advertisercategories, int positions)
    {
        this.InventorySpaceID = inventoryspaceid;
        this.InventoryName = inventoryname;
        this.OrderNumber = ordernumber;
        this.InventoryClearanceTypeBit = inventoryclearancetypebit;
        this.InventoryClearanceTypeID = inventoryclearancetypeid;
        this.InventoryProductTypeID = inventoryproducttypeid;
        this.InventoryTypeID = inventorytypeid;
        this.InventoryGroupAdvertiserCategories = inventorygroupadvertisercategories != null
                                                    ? inventorygroupadvertisercategories.Split('|').ToList()
                                                    : new List<string>();
        this.AdvertiserCategories = advertisercategories != null
                                        ? advertisercategories.Split('|').ToList()
                                        : new List<string>();
        this.Positions = positions;
        this.ScheduledInvSpaces = new List<ScheduledInvSpace>();
        this.AvailableLength = ScheduledInvSpaces.Count * 5;
    }

    public InvSpace(int inventoryspaceid, string inventoryname, int ordernumber, int inventoryclearancetypebit, int inventoryclearancetypeid, int inventoryproducttypeid, int inventorytypeid, string inventorygroupadvertisercategories, string advertisercategories, int positions, List<ScheduledInvSpace> scheduledinvspaces)
    {
        this.InventorySpaceID = inventoryspaceid;
        this.InventoryName = inventoryname;
        this.OrderNumber = ordernumber;
        this.InventoryClearanceTypeBit = inventoryclearancetypebit;
        this.InventoryClearanceTypeID = inventoryclearancetypeid;
        this.InventoryProductTypeID = inventoryproducttypeid;
        this.InventoryTypeID = inventorytypeid;
        this.InventoryGroupAdvertiserCategories = inventorygroupadvertisercategories != null
                                                    ? inventorygroupadvertisercategories.Split('|').ToList()
                                                    : new List<string>();
        this.AdvertiserCategories = advertisercategories != null
                                        ? advertisercategories.Split('|').ToList()
                                        : new List<string>();
        this.Positions = positions;
        this.ScheduledInvSpaces = scheduledinvspaces;
        this.AvailableLength = ScheduledInvSpaces.Count * 5;
    }
}

class InvSpaceResultEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<USP_GetAvailableScheduledInventorySpacesResult>
{
    public bool Equals(USP_GetAvailableScheduledInventorySpacesResult x, USP_GetAvailableScheduledInventorySpacesResult y)
    {
        return Equals(x.InventorySpaceID, y.InventorySpaceID) && Equals(x.EventID, y.EventID);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(USP_GetAvailableScheduledInventorySpacesResult x)
    {
        return x.InventorySpaceID.GetHashCode();
    }
}

    public class ScheduledInvSpace
{
    public int ScheduledInventorySpaceID { get; set; }
    public int SlotID { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public int? ContractOrderID { get; set; }
    public int? RotationID { get; set; }
    public int InventorySequence { get; set; }
    public string InventoryGroupAdvertiserCategoryRule { get; set; }
    public string AdvertiserCategoryRule { get; set; }
    public int? PositionRule { get; set; }
    public string BumpRule { get; set; }
    public string ClearanceRule { get; set; }
    public bool? Bonus { get; set; }

    public ScheduledInvSpace()
    {
    }

    public ScheduledInvSpace(int scheduledinventoryspaceid, int slotid, int length, int inventorysequence, string inventorygroupadvertisercategoryrule, string advertisercategoryrule, int? positionrule, string bumprule, string clearancerule, bool? bonus)
    {
        this.ScheduledInventorySpaceID = scheduledinventoryspaceid;
        this.SlotID = slotid;
        this.Length = length;
        this.ContractOrderID = null;
        this.RotationID = null;
        this.InventorySequence = inventorysequence;
        this.InventoryGroupAdvertiserCategoryRule = inventorygroupadvertisercategoryrule;
        this.AdvertiserCategoryRule = advertisercategoryrule;
        this.PositionRule = positionrule;
        this.BumpRule = bumprule;
        this.ClearanceRule = clearancerule;
        this.Bonus = bonus;
    }

    public ScheduledInvSpace(int scheduledinventoryspaceid, int slotid, int length, int? contractorderid, int? rotationid, int inventorysequence, string inventorygroupadvertisercategoryrule, string advertisercategoryrule, int? positionrule, string bumprule, string clearancerule, bool? bonus)
    {
        this.ScheduledInventorySpaceID = scheduledinventoryspaceid;
        this.SlotID = slotid;
        this.Length = length;
        this.ContractOrderID = contractorderid;
        this.RotationID = rotationid;
        this.InventorySequence = inventorysequence;
        this.InventoryGroupAdvertiserCategoryRule = inventorygroupadvertisercategoryrule;
        this.AdvertiserCategoryRule = advertisercategoryrule;
        this.PositionRule = positionrule;
        this.BumpRule = bumprule;
        this.ClearanceRule = clearancerule;
        this.Bonus = bonus;
    }
}

class SheduledInvSpaceResultEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<USP_GetAvailableScheduledInventorySpacesResult>
{
    public bool Equals(USP_GetAvailableScheduledInventorySpacesResult x, USP_GetAvailableScheduledInventorySpacesResult y)
    {
        return Equals(x.ScheduledInventorySpaceID, y.ScheduledInventorySpaceID);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(USP_GetAvailableScheduledInventorySpacesResult x)
    {
        return x.ScheduledInventorySpaceID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I am populating this hierarchy using the following code:

```
List<Evt>games = results
                            .Distinct(new EvtResultEqualityComparer())
                            .Select(e => 
                                new Evt(e.NetCodeID.Value, e.EventID.Value, e.SiteID.Value, e.HomeGame.Value, e.Days, e.DayBit.Value, e.EventIDRC.Value, results
                                    .Distinct(new InvSpaceResultEqualityComparer())
                                    .Where(i => i.EventID.Value == e.EventID.Value && i.InventoryProductTypeID.Value == (ProductTypes[i.EventIDRC.Value % ProductTypes.Count]))
                                    .Select(i => 
                                        new InvSpace(i.InventorySpaceID.Value, i.InventoryName, i.OrderNumber.Value, i.InventoryClearanceTypeBit.Value, i.InventoryClearanceTypeID.Value, i.InventoryProductTypeID.Value, i.InventoryTypeID.Value, i.InventoryGroupAdvertiserCategoryRule, i.AdvertiserCategoryRule, i.PositionRule.GetValueOrDefault(0), results
                                            .Distinct(new SheduledInvSpaceResultEqualityComparer())
                                            .Where(s => s.EventID.Value == e.EventID.Value && s.InventorySpaceID.Value == i.InventorySpaceID.Value)
                                            .Select(s => 
                                                new ScheduledInvSpace(s.ScheduledInventorySpaceID.Value, s.SlotID.Value, s.Length.Value, s.ContractOrderID, s.RotationID, s.InventorySequence.Value, s.InventoryGroupAdvertiserCategoryRule, s.AdvertiserCategoryRule, s.PositionRule.GetValueOrDefault(0), s.BumpRule, s.ClearanceRule, s.Bonus)).ToList()
                                                )).Where(i => i.AvailableLength >= length).ToList())).ToList();
```

Comment: and what is the generated SQL? Have you examined the query plan?

Comment: Pleun: The issue is not the SQL it is the conversion from the Linq-to-Sql resultset to the hierarchical objects that is slow. I can get the result back to my application in under 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use LINQ group by. It's easier to read if you avoid Lambda expression group by and just stick with select from group by.